# Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-zookeeper

```html
WARN  [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

The mistake was repeated all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Zookeeper server in command. Try this:

1. Go to Cloudera Manager -> Zookeeper -> Instances
2. Check the hosts of your servers
3. Use this command to check the connection:

   kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server :9092 --topic

Answer (score 0):

**WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect**
Not sure if this applies in this case, but 
***"server null"*** indicates that you have forgotten to pass the server parameters while running your ZK CLI.
Your command should be like this:
**./zkCli.sh -server *hostname:port***

If you don't specify port it will take the default 2181.